# Mahout: Using two DataModels in one Recommender

Tags: java, machine-learning, mahout

I am trying to create a simple recommendation engine with two sets of boolean preference data. I want to use one data set to calculate UserSimilarity and UserNeighborhoods, and then use those neighborhoods to make recommendations from a second set of boolean preference data.

I seem to have this working, but the problem is that when I go to calculate recommendations, if a user has neighbors based on the first data set, but is not present in the second data set (though their neighbors are) it produces no recommendations.

Here's RecommendationBuilder code:

```
  recommenderBuilder = new RecommenderBuilder() {
      public Recommender buildRecommender(DataModel recommendationModel) throws TasteException {
          UserSimilarity similarity = new LogLikelihoodSimilarity(trainingModel);
          UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood(10, 0.7, similarity, recommendationModel);

          return new GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender(recommendationModel, neighborhood, similarity);
      }
  };
```

And here's a sample of the trainingModel file

```
1,111
2,222

2,111
2,222

3,111
3,222
```

And the recommendationModel file

```
1,91
1,92

2,91
```

Running this recommends 92 for user 2, but throws a `NoSuchUserException` when it gets to user 3.

Sol... Is there any way to produce recommendations from one data set based on similarities calculated on another data set, without needing to have all users present in the second data set?

Here's the complete code I'm working with right now:

```
private DataModel trainingModel;
private DataModel recommendationModel;
private RecommenderEvaluator evaluator;
private RecommenderIRStatsEvaluator evaluator2;
private RecommenderBuilder recommenderBuilder;
private DataModelBuilder modelBuilder;

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws IOException, TasteException {

    trainingModel = new GenericBooleanPrefDataModel(
        GenericBooleanPrefDataModel.toDataMap(new FileDataModel(new File("/music.csv")))
    );

    recommendationModel = new GenericBooleanPrefDataModel(
            GenericBooleanPrefDataModel.toDataMap(new FileDataModel(new File("/movies.csv")))
    );

    evaluator = new AverageAbsoluteDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator();
    evaluator2 = new GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator();


    recommenderBuilder = new RecommenderBuilder() {
        public Recommender buildRecommender(DataModel model) throws TasteException {
            UserSimilarity similarity = new LogLikelihoodSimilarity(trainingModel);
            UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood(10, 0.7, similarity, model);

            return new GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);
        }
    };

    modelBuilder = new DataModelBuilder() {
        public DataModel buildDataModel( FastByIDMap<PreferenceArray> trainingData ) {
            return new GenericBooleanPrefDataModel( GenericBooleanPrefDataModel.toDataMap(trainingData) );
        }        
    };

}
```

And then running this method

```
    @Override
    public void testData() throws TasteException {

        double score = evaluator.evaluate(recommenderBuilder, modelBuilder, trainingModel, 0.9, 1.0);
        System.out.println("calculated score: " + score);

        try {
            IRStatistics stats = evaluator2.evaluate(
                    recommenderBuilder, modelBuilder, trainingModel, null, 2,
                    0.0,
                    1.0
            );
            System.out.println("recall: " + stats.getRecall());
            System.out.println("precision: " + stats.getPrecision());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("throwing " + t);
        }

        List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommenderBuilder.buildRecommender(recommendationModel).recommend(1,2);
        System.out.println("user 1");
        for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) { System.out.println(recommendation);}

        recommendations = recommenderBuilder.buildRecommender(recommendationModel).recommend(2,2);
        System.out.println("user 2");
        for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) { System.out.println(recommendation);}

        try {
            recommendations = recommenderBuilder.buildRecommender(recommendationModel).recommend(3,2);
            System.out.println("user 3");
            for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) { System.out.println(recommendation);}
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("throwing " + t);
        }
}
```

Produces this output:

> calculated score: 0.7033357620239258 recall: 1.0 precision: 1.0 user 1
>   user 2 RecommendedItem[item:9222, value:0.8516679]
>   throwing org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.common.NoSuchUserException: 3

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are describing, and roughly how you are describing it. The data set that powers the user similarity metric could indeed be different from the data set over which recommendations are made. The user similarity metric could in fact be based on anything you like.

However it does need to be able to produce a user-user similarity for any pair in the data set used to make recommendations. I suggest you simply special-case this in your `UserSimilarity` implementation to return 0 or something when one user is unknown.

Comment: I considered this. But does this mean that the user-user similarity for people in the data set for recommendations is actually used? The second data set is very sparse and noisy, so I don't want patterns in it to affect how recommendations are picked.

Comment: The user-based rec algorithm is essentially just a weighted-average algorithm, where the weights are similarities. Yes they would be used, even if their source is completely unrelated. It doesn't matter where they are from, to the rec algorithm. Whether your data gives good answers this way depends on the data.

Comment: If what I'm trying to do is decide that users 1 and 2 are similar based on data set A, and then suggest to user 2 everything that user 1 likes in data set B; is my approach going to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, but users 1 and 2 need to exist in A and B. (Or, your code needs to help it pretend that they are.) A recommender does more than recommend everything another likes -- it's a weighted average over many users. I assume that's what you mean.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was just being simplistic. Though with a data set of only 2 users and boolean and preference I guess it would have to recommend everything user 2 doesn't already like, or nothing.

Comment: One follow up question: I have added a special case for itemId 0, but am having trouble adding a preference for itemId 0 for a user before getting a recommendation for them. It appears that the GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender implementation of Recommender simply throws an UnsupportedOperationException.